# How to get the minimum value of a product using minimum function?

Tags: java, arrays, list, selenium

```
 my data1=[{"iphone6","16000"},{"iphone7","17000"},{"iphone8","10000"}]
```

i want my output as iphone8 ,10000
    but it giving exception Index 0 out of bounds for length 0 error

```
     public String getMinLaptopPrice(ArrayList<String[]> data) {
           //min value 
              String min = data.get(0)[1];
              for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++) {
               String cur = data.get(i)[1];

            int S = cur.compareTo(min);
             if(S>0) {
                 min = cur;
              }
             }
            return min;
          }
```

Comment: You are not checking that your list is not empty, and you are not checking that the arrays inside it are not empty. You should add checks before you access `[0]` and `[1]` as well as before using `get(0)`.

Comment: how create your data .... some thing like this...
`String[] d1 = {"iphone6","16000"};
        String[] d2 = {"iphone7","17000"};
        String[] d3 = {"iphone8","10000"};
        ArrayList<String[]> data1=new ArrayList<>();
        data1.add(d1);
        data1.add(d2);
        data1.add(d3);`

Comment: yes Istiaque i create data this way.but i scrap this thing from flipkart side.not manually doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] d1 = {"iphone6","16000"};
        String[] d2 = {"iphone7","17000"};
        String[] d3 = {"iphone8","10000"};
        ArrayList<String[]> data1=new ArrayList<>();
        data1.add(d1);
        data1.add(d2);
        data1.add(d3);
        String[] d = getMinLaptopPrice(data1);
        System.out.print(d[0] + ", " + d[1]);
    }

    public static String[] getMinLaptopPrice(ArrayList<String[]> data) {
        int value_min = Integer.parseInt(data.get(0)[1]);
        String key_min = "";
        for(int i = 1; i < data.size(); i++) {
            int value = Integer.parseInt(data.get(i)[1]);
            if (value < value_min) {
                value_min = value;
                key_min = data.get(i)[0];
            }
        }
        String[] d = {key_min, String.valueOf(value_min)};
        return d;
    }
}
```

and the output is:

```
iphone8, 10000
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong compare method,for int value,you can compare the value directly

```
public String getMinLaptopPrice(ArrayList<String[]> data) {
     int s = Integer.parseInt(data.get(0)[1]);
     String min = data.get(0)[0];
     for(int i=1;i<data.size();i++) {
        int value = Integer.parseInt(data.get(i)[1]);//convert string to int vlaue
        if(value<s) {
            min = data.get(i)[0];
            s= value;
        }
     }
     return min;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the Exception is the initialization of the `min` variable. Set it to Integer.MAX_VALUE and parse the data. On zero length arrays you can't access the data.

Generally

- Finding minimum: init at max value
- Finding maximum: init at min value
- Check array size ahead of accessing.

Comment: It's a string, not an integer.

Comment: oh yes, then parsing must be used

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code

```
public Integer getMinLaptopPrice(ArrayList<String[]> data) { 
        int min = Integer.valueOf(data.get(0)[1]);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            int cur = Integer.valueOf(data.get(i)[1]); 
            if (cur < min) {
                min = cur;
            }
        }
        return min;
    }
```

in your code, you try to compare two string Object instead of there value...
so i convert all amount data into `Integer` and compare minimum value by if condition... and also change method return type to `Integer` ...

Comment: Hi@Istiaque Hossain again this code showing same error in the line  int min = Integer.valueOf(data.get(0)[1]);

Comment: this one showing index 0 out of bound for length 0 exception

Comment: may be you input parameter has no data

Comment: thank u.my input parameter has no data.thats why it showing error

Comment: If my answer help you to solve your problem .....plz give me up vote or accept this answer